# OrderByDescending before AddRange Linq Query

Tags: c#, linq

I have two `List` , `promolist` and `packagelist`. `packagelist` data must be the first then `packagelist`, both `list` must `OrderByDescending` and `ThenByDescending` the `level` then `totalclick`

Bellow is what I tried

```
promolist.OrderByDescending(o =>  o.packagelevel.level).ThenByDescending(o => o.totalclick);
promolist.AddRange(packagelist.OrderByDescending(o => o.packagelevel.level).ThenByDescending(o => o.totalclick));
return promolist;
```

The result is nearly what I want, `promolist` is before `packagelist` , and `packagelist` have order correctly, just the **`promolist` not do any `OrderByDescending` or `ThenByDescending`**

Comment: Linq is not manipulating the lists. Linq is creating a new list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The outcome of `OrderBy` is a new enumerable that you need to assign and evaluate. You don't do anything with the outcome.

You need this:

```
promolist = promolist.OrderByDescending(o =>  o.packagelevel.level)
                     .ThenByDescending(o => o.totalclick)
                     .ToList();
```

Comment: hi, thanks for reply, what u mean is shoud add `promolist =` before `AddRange` ?

Comment: No, `promolist.AddRange` adds the result of the enumerable to the `promoList`. That works. The `promolist.OrderByDescending` doesn't work.

Comment: sorry, I don't get it ,so what the final code look like ?

Comment: Only replace the first line in your code by my answer code.

Comment: oh, my mistake, thanks for your answer , very helpful to me